# prepareForSegue not being called inside UIBarButtonItem selector

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

Here is my code where I register the UIBarButtonItems and its Selector Function.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    var edit = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("editTruck"))
    let delete = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Delete", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "deleteTruck")
    let menu = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "menu"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self.revealViewController(), action: "rightRevealToggle:")

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [menu,delete,edit]

    self.title = truckName.text

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer())
}

func editTruck(){

    println("insdie edittruck")

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("editTruck", sender: self)

     func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){
    println("inside prepare")            
        if segue.identifier == "editTruck"{
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController
            let topView = vc?.topViewController as! AddTruckViewController
            topView.truckNameValue = name.text!
            topView.totalFuelupsValue = totalFuelups.text!
            topView.totalDistanceTrackedValue = totalDistanceTracked.text!
            topView.truckYearValue = truckYear.text!
            topView.truckMakeValue = truckMake.text!
            topView.truckModelValue = truckModel.text!
            topView.truckImagevalue = truckImage.image!
            topView.engineMakeValue = engineMake.text!
            topView.engineModelValue = engineModel.text!
            topView.horsePowerValue = horsePower.text!
            topView.axleValue = axle.text!
            topView.trailerTypeValue = trailerType.text!
            topView.steerTireMakeValue = steerTireMake.text!
            topView.steerTireModelValue = steerTireModel.text!
            topView.steerTireSizeValue = steerTireSize.text!
            topView.driveTireMakeValue = driveTireMake.text!
            topView.driveTireModelValue = driveTireModel.text!
            topView.driveTireSizeValue = driveTireSize.text!
            topView.transmissionMakeValue = transmissionMake.text!
            topView.transmissionModelValue = transmissionModel.text!
            topView.distanceUnitValue = distanceUnit.text!
            topView.volumeUnitValue = volumeUnit.text!
        }
    }
}
```

In IB I Control Dragged from the TruckSpecsViewController (the yellow icon at the top since my buttons are created programmatically),where my above code is from, to the Scene where I want to segue to. I added the identifier to that segue of "editTruck". In the code above the performSegueWithIdentifier works but the prepareForSegue doesnt. No errors or anything it just never gets called.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why is your `prepareForSegue:sender` method inside your `editTruck` method? Move the  `prepareForSegue:sender` method to the same level as your `editTruck` method in your View Controller. I expect the change of scope will fix your problem.

Comment: Ok I must not understand it well enough. So when the edit truck button is fired I need it to segue but without a segue on it from IB I thought this would handle it. Do you mind explaining how the segue would fire if it wasnt inside the button's action?

Comment: @Suzukijak3  your viewController class takes care of calling prepareForSegue. It's an implicit method that you can rewrite if you need to prepare something before the segue is executed. So, you need to change the scope and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you both so much, that was the issue. I appreciate it. How do I accept an answer in a comment?

Comment: @RoboticCat will someone add the answer so I can accept it for you.

Comment: @KioCoan one of you can answer it and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `prepareForSegue:sender` method to the same level as your `editTruck` method in your View Controller. The change of scope will fix your problem.

iOS automatically calls the `prepareForSegue:sender` method on your View Controller either in response to a segue in a Storyboard or by calling `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` in code.

You never call `prepareForSegue:sender` yourself; you just implement this method in your View Controller.